# Is there a way to export variable in VBS?

Tags: vbscript

I have two Visual Basic Script files on my desktop, one called "Master" and the other called "Servant". I want the Master script to execute a task request to the Servant and wait for it to response. Once the Servant completes the request, I want the Servant to export a confirmation to the Master that the task has been completed so that the Master can then carry on to the next line of code.

Is the above structure viable in VBS?

Comment: That is possible. Why do you need both scripts running instead of importing code from from the Servant file?

Comment: Thank you for replying. It is because the task which the Master requires the Servant to execute will potentially hang the Servant script. Therefore, I would rather have the Master in control to terminate the Servant when it is hanged.

Comment: Take a look at [asynchronous ping example](http://pastebin.com/gwGLXmVH)

Comment: I guess better to solve the code hanging issue rather than resort such methods.

Comment: Thank you omegastripes for your reply. Yes indeed it is better and this is only to be the last mean.

Comment: As you can see in the example by the above link, there is no need to create 2 separate scripts. To do the task, the script runs itself (thus creating separate wscript.exe process), connects to master, execute another part of code and returns data.